# “Entity Data Model” missing in datasources in VS 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, datasource

- I want to add an "Entity Data Model" in data sources in a new project.
- When I click "add new data source" the Data Source Configuration Wizard window will pop-up and will let me choose a data source type, the problem is the "Entity Data Model" is not in the list, only the database, service, project, and sharepoint is in the list.

---

If you watch this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ckx5hXK4pAE he has the database model "Entity Data Model"

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity Data Model is not in default into VS, you need to install entity framework. 
search for Entity framework into Nuget package, install EF 5 or 6 as per your requirement and then add model.

Probably you should start with EF tutorial first..